# Where to hold static information for game logic?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The context for this question is:

- A Google App Engine backend for a two-person multiplayer turn-based card game
- The game revolves around different combinations of cards giving rise to different scores in the game

Obviously, one would store the state of a game in the GAE datastore, but I'm not sure on the approach for the design of the game logic itself.  It seems I might have two choices:

1. Store entries in the datastore with a key that is a sorted list of the valid combinations of cards that can be player.  These will then map to the score values.  When a player tries to play a combination of cards, the server-side python will sort the combination appropriately and lookup the key.  If it succeeds, it can do the necessary updates for the score, if it fails then the combination wasn't valid.
2. Store the valid combinations as a python dictionary written into the server-side code and perform the same lookups as above to test the validity/get the score but without a trip to the datastore.

From a cost point of view (datastore lookups aren't free), option 2 seems like it would be better.  But then there is the performance of the instance itself - will the startup time, processing time, memory usage start to tip me into greater expense?

There's also the code maintanence issue of constructing that Python dictionary, but I can bash together some scripts to help me write the code for that on the infrequently occasions that the logic changes.  I think there will be on the order of 1000 card combinations (that can produce a score) of between 2 and 6 cards if that helps anyone who wants to quantify the problem.

I'm starting out with this design, and the summary of the above is whether it is sensible to store the static logic of this kind of game in the datastore, or simply keep it as part of the CPU bound logic?  What are the pros and cons of both approaches?

Comment: don't forget that it's not like you get to choose between spinning up an instance and looking at the datastore - to look at the datastore you've already spun up an instance to do that with. So you might as well calculate your lookup on the instance itself as it's starting up anyway either way!

Comment: I don't know much about the game but personally I don't think you need a dictionnary. The code that will generate the list of valid combination could just be used to determine if the player has a winning hand.

Comment: @the_lotus:  That would be true if the combinations were computable, but they aren't in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### So just for comparison to the information above:

In a standard deck of cards there are 52 unique cards. With 5 cards in a hand, there are  2,598,960 unique hands possible to get dealt.

```
    Here's a break down of the combinatorial math:

      n = 52 cards total
      r = 5 cards in hand

    number of combinations = n! / (r! - (n-r)!)
      = 52! / (5! * 47!)
      = (52 * 51 * 50 * 49 * 48) / (5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1)
      = 2,598,960
```

And to simplify the example a bit more, lets compare the numbers to 5 card stud poker. Poker has 9 different types of "scoring" hands (Royal Flush, Straight Flush, Four of a kind, Full House, Flush, Straight, Three of a kind, Two Pairs, One Pair).

The odds that you have nothing in your hand are 50.11%
    The odds that you have any of the above combinations is 49.89%.

The number of possible hand combinations in 5 card stud is huge, there are only 4 suits of cards, 13 numbers on the cards, and 9 different "scoring" combination type

I hope that this example clearly illustrates that it would be a huge undertaking to generate and store all of the possible "scoring" combinations of 5 card stud in a database.

### What this means to you:

Since I do not know the rules of your game, the main thing you need to consider is the number of different "scoring" combination types.

You didn't really specify how unique / different your possible scoring combinations are in your game. The closer the number of combination types is to the number of combinations, the more custom "scoring" rules there are.

Using the 52 card deck example above, if each unique hand had it's own unique score You would quickly have upwards of 3 million database entries. In which case I would heavily suggest you get many databases that support a MapReduce query capability (e.g. Cassandra + Hadoop) that would allow you to easily scale your infrastructure to reduce query times. I would imagine that having 3 million unique scoring combinations is very unlikely though. That would make the rules of the game tremendously complex, and probably make your game unplayable.

Since you said that your game will have around 1000 hand combinations of 2-6 cards, let's simplify the example and get a ballpark number. Using the largest hand possible (6 cards in hand), there are 3,003 possible hands in a 12 card deck. Assuming that number of different combination types, suits, and numbered cards scales evenly (there is some fantasy math in here), you are looking at having around ~1,500 "scoring" combinations.

### The bottom line:

The application logic needed to "score" winning hands for your game is the very same logic that the players of your game will need to understand in order to play (assuming that this game requires any skill / understanding at all, and it does not purely rely on luck). The more complicated it is, the harder the game will be for the players. I can only assume that the game logic isn't that complicated.

I would find it unlikely that you only have 16 cards in your deck. It would seem reasonable to have a couple hundred cards with several grouping types used for uniqueness (e.g. suit on a poker card, or mana type on a Magic the Gathering card). Assuming that you have more cards and combination types than a basic poker game, then it would seem very reasonable to conclude that it would take far more effort to store the various combinations than to include the logic of your game in the code. Also, every time you add a new rule your storage requirements would jump up in orders of magnitude, rather than scale linearly.

Since you will inevitably develop the code necessary to implement the rules of the card game, you might as well see how long it takes to "score" an arbitrary hand of cards. I would caution against premature optimization, and suggest that you prototype your design. 
I would suggest you have configurable logic module that allows you to easily alter the rules of your game as needed. once the rules are solidified and unlikely to change, then I would look at optimizing your application code as needed. From the maintainability perspective, storing all of your application logic in a database is nuts (I think most maintenance programmers would agree with me on this). After you try to "fix" (e.g. normalize, migrate, transform) the data generated by a few scripts you just "bashed together" (your words) you will end up bashing your head into your keyboard.

As far as GAE pricing is concerned, the number of instances you will need will be based on your users / demand. Generally the limiting factor on scaling systems is Disk IOPS not the CPU. In the long run, I bet you would take a much bigger hit on performance as well as pricing by storing all of your application logic in a database.

### Sources:

1) A Combinatorial Calculator: http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php

B) Poker Odds: http://www.durangobill.com/Poker.html

Comment: You're right that I've not been very clear - I've clarified the question a bit to indicate that I only expect to have 1000 combinations (perhaps permutations would be a better term) of cards that can produce a score.  The card game is more of the Magic variety, so the ability to score from the player's perspective will depend on the cards' properties, so numerical logic as in a standard card deck/poker game will be harder to apply

Comment: What changes have you made to clarify your question? I can't tell any difference. Also, would Magic be an example you could relate to more? I could edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: I added "(that can produce a score)" into the text - I think that's thrown you off with the possibility of millions of combinations, when in the question I'm pointing out that I will only have on the order of 1000

Comment: I only used poker in the example to help distinguish the difference between non-unique combinations and unique combination types, and that the ratio of combinations to combination types was quite large. I used poker as an analogy to a game with unknown rules, and I think that the general concepts still apply. My point was that it is very likely that the logic required to produce a score for a hand of cards will likely be much simpler and performant compared to database lookups.

Comment: Yeah, I think that this is tending towards my dictionary lookup in the Python server code rather than round-tripping to the datastore.  It will also make modifying the game a bit easier (don't have to keep dropping data). I just wanted to see if I was doing something patently stupid in the design!

Comment: Based on your comments, that's what I would do. I'd create a module that can identify the generic combination types (e.g. A Monster card and 1/2/3/4 mana cards) and then if you cant' score the hand, lookup specific unique combination types declared in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If the logic is fixed, keep it in your code. Maybe you can procedurally generate the dicts on startup. If there is a dynamic component to the logic (something you want to update frequently), a data store might be a better bet, but it sounds like that's not applicable here. Unless the number of combinations runs over the millions, and you'd want to trade speed in favour of a lower memory footprint, stick with putting it in the application itself.